# Use RMI to connect to JMX in local mode (without a port)

Tags: java, rmi, jmx

The [JMX agent docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/agent.html#local) explains there's a local mode when `com.sun.management.jmxremote.port` is not supplied.

The doc also seems to imply this requires temporary files and is only understood by JConsole.

I am wondering is above correct and if so how to connect to the agent using RMI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called the [Attach API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/attach/). Technically, it does use a port, but it does not require the target JVM to have pre-launched a JMX Connector Server. Once connected, the target JVM will launch a new connector server and the [JMXServiceURL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/remote/JMXServiceURL.html) of that server can be retrieved from the [VirtualMachine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/com/sun/tools/attach/VirtualMachine.html) instance by looking up the [agent property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/com/sun/tools/attach/VirtualMachine.html#getAgentProperties()) **com.sun.management.jmxremote.localConnectorAddress**.